# How can I get list of elements or data which are on same level with same attributes?

Tags: html, selenium, xpath, text, selenium-webdriver

I have one web application which have one HTML page.

In this page structure is like this:

```
<div class = 'abc'>
           <div class = 'pqr'>test1</div>
</div>
<div class = 'abc'>
           <div class = 'pqr'>-</div>
</div>
<div class = 'abc'>
           <div class = 'pqr'>-</div>
</div>
<div class = 'abc'>
           <div class = 'pqr'>test2</div>
</div>
<div class = 'abc'>
           <div class = 'pqr'>-</div>
</div>
```

Here I want to take data from test1 to test2.

I have tried xpath with [Node Number] But I have found all nodes at [1] level.

Is there any way to get all data or List of elements test1 to test2 with "-" ?

Comment: Post the xpath you tried, the elements selected by using that xpath, and the elements that should be selected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have seen this kind of issue before.

You have to use following-sibling here.

- First I use this type of xpath :

  **//div[text()='test1']/..//following-sibling::div[@class='pqr' and not(contains(text(),'test'))]**
- Then you need to change script. **"Note : I have written code in JAVA"**

  Logic :

  **while(element found text = '-')
  {
  //get data here
  }**

Please try this approach.

Answer (score 2):

I *guess* you want the following xpath :

```
(//div[@class='pqr'])[position()<=4]
```

Notice the brackets `()` before `position()` predicate.

output in [xpath tester](http://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html#ad-output) :

```
Element='<div class="pqr">test1</div>'
Element='<div class="pqr">-</div>'
Element='<div class="pqr">-</div>'
Element='<div class="pqr">test2</div>'
```

Comment: I will try this approach also.

Answer (score -1):

I think you can't use the Test1 and Test2 elements as identifiers because they are on the same line as the nodes you want to collect. Otherwise, I think you can use findElements(by.Xpath("patern_to_search")). that will return you a collection of elements that are matching your pattern.

Answer (score -1):

one more way without using xpath:

```
   List<WebElement> element = driver.findElements(By.className("pqr"));     
   for(int i=0;i<element.size()-1;i++){
        System.out.println(element.get(i).getText());
   }
```

Comment: why is this downvoted?, the question was "Is there any way to get all data or List of elements test1 to test2 with "-" ?"....The code I gave definitely works its one of the way....It would be helpful if a person gives the reason for downvoting